# scala jdbc SQLContext issue

Tags: oracle, scala, jdbc

I am getting a error - load is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext. I have tried a few things like using the import explicits after defining the SQLContext, but does not work. Any one faced this issue?

Here is the .sbt file

```
name := "sparkJDBC"
version := "0.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.5.1" 
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.tika" % "tika-core" % "1.11"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.tika" % "tika-parsers" % "1.11"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.10" % "1.0.0"
```

Here is the scala code

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;



object sparkJDBC {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application").setMaster("local[2]").set("spark.executor.memory","1g")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    var sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    import sqlContext.implicits._
    val chrttype = sqlContext.load("jdbc", 
    Map("url" -> "jdbc:oracle:thin:gductv1/gductv1@//localhost:1521/XE1",
    "dbtable" -> "chrt_typ"))
    val clntlvl1  = sqlContext.load("jdbc", 
   Map("url" -> "jdbc:oracle:thin:gductv1/gductv1@//localhost:1521/XE1", 
   "dbtable" -> "clnt_lvl1"))
    val join2 = chrttyp.join(clntlvl1,chrttyp.col("chrt_typ_key")===clntlvl1("lvl1_key"))
    join2.foreach(println)
    join2.printSchema()
    }
}
```

Here is the error file.

```
[info] Compiling 2 Scala sources to C:\apps\spark-2.1.0\ScalaFiles\target\scala-2.10\classes...
[error] C:\apps\spark-2.1.0\ScalaFiles\src\main\scala\SimpleApp2.scala:33: value load is not a member of org.apache.spar
k.sql.SQLContext
[error]     val chrttype = sqlContext.load("jdbc",
[error]                               ^
[error] C:\apps\spark-2.1.0\ScalaFiles\src\main\scala\SimpleApp2.scala:36: value load is not a member of org.apache.spar
k.sql.SQLContext
[error]     val clntlvl1  = sqlContext.load("jdbc",
[error]                                ^
[error] C:\apps\spark-2.1.0\ScalaFiles\src\main\scala\SimpleApp2.scala:39: not found: value chrttyp
[error]     val join2 = chrttyp.join(clntlvl1,chrttyp.col("chrt_typ_key")===clntlvl1("lvl1_key"))
[error]                 ^
[error] three errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

Comment: Does anyone have a link/resource/suggested reading with a complete JDBC import example via scala and sbt?

Comment: Incompatible Spark versions, possibly incompatible Scala versions.

Comment: I am new to this so help me on this please - given the versions that you see on the code and the config files, do you notice something ?

Comment: You use Spark 1.5 for core, 1.0 (!) for SQL, and mix Scala versions.